# Ubuntu 14.04 Audio Issues

Tags: 14.04, sound, alienware

I am relatively new to Ubuntu (using 14.04) and am looking for assistance in solving these audio issues. My computer is an alienware m14r2, and has a SoundBlaster Recon 3di sound card. My speakers work; however, my main issue is that when I plug in my headphones the audio continues to play through the speakers. When I look under sound settings, it shows that when I plug my headphones in, audio services are transferred from the analog-audio (speakers) to the headphones. Yet, the volume continues to be played through the speakers. Additionally, when performing multiple system diagnostics including looking through alsamixer, it shows my soundcard to be an intel card and not the soundblaster. I'm wondering if the issue could relate to the fact that the system is recognizing the integrated sound card as being the primary sound card for my system and not the SoundBlaster card, which, in my system, is the only card connecting the headphone jacks. I have tried all fixes listed on this forum and others for similar issues and none seem to work. Any and all help is appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Others who may share in this issue, I finally came across a solution:

First, open the terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)

Open the alsamixer using the command:

```
      alsamixer
```

A basic GUI will open. Press the F5 Key to expand the menu to include all options

Scroll rightward until you are hovering over the option titled HP/Speaker Auto-Detect

Press M to turn the feature to On

Press the ESC key to close the menu

Exit the terminal window